# Azure Storage - Use Blob from Private Container in <img> tag

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have Azure Container created and set to Private. The permission must be set to Private because the content is only viewable to logged in user. However, I am intended to use the blob in  tag. This is not possible when the Container is set to Private. Is there a way around this? Or have anybody else encounter the same problem?

All the code sample I have downloaded (PhluffyPhotos, MyPictures) from CodePlex / Code Project always set the container to Public (Container / Blob).

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider using Shared Access Signatures. With these signatures, you can give your user temporary access to a Blob in a private container.

Eugenio Pace's article explains exactly what you're trying to do: [Windows Azure Guidance – Using Shared Key Signatures for images in a-Expense](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eugeniop/archive/2010/04/13/windows-azure-guidance-using-shared-key-signatures-for-images-in-a-expense.aspx)

Comment: +1 to this answer. In one of my website, in order to protect my images (prevent them from being inked by other sites) I utilized SAS. I generated a SAS with very short time (i.e. 5 seconds) in my backend code, and put the BLOB URL with SAS to my view (I was using MVC). So it can be shown on my web page. But others cannot use this URL to retrieve the image since the SAS had expired.

Comment: There was discussions on this matter as well on MSDN forum, but the conclusion is basically use one of the three approaches in the link that Sandrino sent:
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/dbfb9d13-d463-4461-b51f-466261617cb7
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/6b4ff906-c303-44b5-8b94-153e4edae201

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the container private and use your web app as a proxy to download file from the container then serve it via a handler.