# How do I SECURELY display images from Azure blob storage in an img tag?

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, nextjs-image

I have a form with an Image upload in my website. whenever the user uploads an image, its saved under a new container with a random unique ID.
In a different page, I want to display that image. but by using an  tag with a src attribute, im compromising the location of the image, as well as its container name to any curious user with a basic understanding of inspect element:
[https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/secret-container-name/image.jpg"](https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/secret-container-name/image.jpg%22)

How can I securely display said image to the user without it being open to everyone?
I am using NextJS, so perhaps the  component could be of any help?

Comment: put some reverse proxy in front. I'd take a look at Azure Front Door. Will solve this problem as well as bringing you added benefits such as caching

Comment: So you're saying that I can host all my blobs in a CDN? How can I do that?

Comment: no, you will still store the images on blob storage. But you channel all the requests to the blob storage through Front Door.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To securely display images from Azure blob storage, please try the following:**

The below permission must be set to ***Private*** because the content is only viewable to logged in user.

- ***Go to Azure portal -> Storage Accounts -> Select containers -> Choose a container -> Change access level to private as below:***

[image]

- Try implementing ***Azure Active Directory*** to authorize access to blob data.
- Try using a user delegation ***SAS*** to grant limited access to blob data.

[image]

**As mentioned by [@silent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1537195/silent) , try storing the images on blob storage and channel all the requests to the blob storage through Front Door.**

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Security recommendations for Blob storage - Azure Storage | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/security-recommendations)

[Azure Storage - Use Blob from Private Container in  tag - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167453/azure-storage-use-blob-from-private-container-in-img-tag?msclkid=acb68a6ed03c11ec93ef890375e629ab)

Comment: Thank you! is there a way to automatically set all created containers to be private from the get-go? (without me having to manually set every new container to be private).

Comment: Hey @Ariel k. had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Comment: I'll tell you what, the Azure front door is great and makes everything run more smoothly, but the problem i've had still exists - the name of the container is still exposed to everyone...

Comment: Please check several related questions on Stack Overflow with examples and discussion that are relevant.[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63888614/how-to-ensure-user-see-the-images-pertaining-to-him-only-from-private-blob-azure)  [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47090962/url-to-access-private-blob-in-azure-storage).